# Obfuscating or removing string literal from all calls to Log-function in Android

Tags: android, string, reverse-engineering, obfuscation

We are building an Android application where we use Timber for Log-output. We have defined our own .e, .d, .v etc functions and use `if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)` to see if we should output the log. This takes care of the issue that we don't want to output Debug-logs in our releases but all the string literals used in our functions calls are still present in the compiled source code. We furthermore use ProGuard for obfuscation. To exemplify, in a class we can have:

```
somObj.normalFunction(variable)
Log.d("This secret class achieved its secret mission!");
```

In our release, this will not be seen in the app logs but if you reverse-engineer the APK you will see something like:

```
q.b(m)
z.a("This secret class achieved its secret mission!");
```

which can give a hint to the hackers about what class they are looking at. 
So what we're looking for is to either be able to completely REMOVE all the Log function calls at compile time (using some pre-processing, annotation or something, but hopefully without having to add something before EVERY function call) OR to obfuscate all the String literal parameters to those function calls. So, two ideal solutions would be if the source, just before compilation, instead looks like:

```
q.b(m);
```

or

```
q.b(m);
z.a("jgasoisamgp23mmwaföfm,ak,ä")
```

Just by thinking I can see two bad ways to achieve this. Either we surround ALL calls to `Log.d` with `if(BuildConfig.DEBUG)` which will make the compiler remove them before compilation. But this is very tideous. OR, we make sure that every time you want to add a log-printout you need to do

```
Log.d(LogClass.getLog(1234))
```

and you then define ALL those logs inside LogClass and then remove them with `if(BuildConfig.DEBUG)` and return null in getLog if that's the case. But that makes it more tideous every time you want to add a log.

So finally, is there any GOOD solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

DISCLAIMER: I work for [PreEmptive](https://preemptive.com), the company that makes [PreEmptive Protection - DashO](https://www.preemptive.com/products/dasho/overview).

DashO is capable of removing calls to specific methods (e.g., Log methods). While this doesn't remove the instructions to load the string literal, just the call itself, DashO also offers String Encryption, which would offer some protection to those string literals.

As an example, I ran this class through DashO:

```
    public class App {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Log.d("Secret message here"); 
        }
    }
```

After removing calls to `Log.d` with String Encryption on, the decompiled output looks like this:

```
    public class App
    {
      public static void main(String[] paramArrayOfString)
      {
        a.replace("Bwpfpb7u|ih}z{?($0&", -12 - -61);
      }
    }
```

DashO offers other protections (e.g., Control Flow Obfuscation) that tend to break decompilers; I've turned those off for this demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is one or some of the following:

1. Use [Timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber) (so you don't need to bother removing things or adding `if` statements). You simply do this once in your `Application#onCreate()`; if you are in DEBUG, then you *plant* a DebugTree that prints to the console. Else, you plant an "empty tree" that does nothing.
2. Simulate [Timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber) but create your own "YourLogger" class and do the same (if you don't want to include a "third-party" library even though it's just one class). So you'd have `YourLogger.v("tag", "string")` and inside you'd do: `if (debug) { Log.v(tag, string); }` and so on and so forth for all other log types.
3. Use Proguard to strip the logging, and what not.

1 and 2 imply you go through your app and replace all `Log.` lines with either `Timber.` or `YourLogger.`
Option 3 wouldn't need that, since the code would be removed during obfuscation and the calls would do nothing, but this is mode complicated (and I haven't done it in years, don't even remember how it's done, probably easy to look it up).

I'd go for 1.

### Update

Since apparently I don't know how to read, I think that in order to achieve this, your only bet is to have some sort of lookup mechanism for the actual text you want to emit/hide.

Strings.xml is the easiest, since it's included with Android and you can even localize the error messages (if that were needed, of course). Yes, there's a lookup time penalty, but I'd say unless you're iterating over thousands of items and logging different strings every time or something, the penalty wont' be noticeable (I don't have data for this, you'd have to benchmark).

Alternatively, instead of relying on resources, you could just use a file, read it, and load the strings in memory... a trade off; do you use more memory at the cost of simplicity and time to code the solution, or do you use the built-in mechanism and pay the CPU time?

Comment: So I'm not sure you read the question. We are using Timber, and plant the tree in the application. So we can use that to remove the output when not in DEBUG. However, this does not at all solve the issue with having string literals present in our code if reverse-engineered. If you read how I exemplify you should understand what I'm after.

Comment: Apologies, I did read, but I misunderstood your intentions. What you *could* do, is to put the log strings in a `strings.xml` (or similar resource) that is present in your DEBUG flavor/variant, and then provide one that has "empty" strings for `release`

Comment: of course that means you'd have to always do `log(getString(R.string.some_error_string))` or similar.

Comment: Okay, so somewhat similar to one of my final examples. But yeah, adding them to xml might be better than having some log-string-class. Still adds that overhead everytime we log. Hoping for something better ;)

Comment: Well, you can roll your own thing (for faster lookup vs the whole resource/getString) but... is it worth? I mean, I'd try it first and see if there's a real penalty here. You can locally cache your logs if you need to do a lot of lookup in a loop or something. You can also use _security through obscurity_ using your own domain language for the strings; instead of "We did X thing", use "WDXT" or whatever (you get the idea). Or.. a combination of all these if this is *really* important; I don't think there's a _magic_ solution. I'd use a flavored strings.xml, works out of the box :)

Comment: Well, the magic solution would be a pre-processor that looks up all function calls to ```Log.*``` and simply removes them from the code before compilation. OR, looks up all those function calls and obliterates the parameter. Does not feel like something very impossible :) Does not feel that far-fetched to write an own shell-solution which iterates through all the code and does that but I get a feeling we would get it wrong a few times before we can trust it.

Comment: Yes, preprocessor, but, there aren't any that I know of. :/

Comment: You _could_ potentially use the C preprocessor, but **(a)** you'd need a one-off global search/replace to turn `Log.d(...)` into something like `LOGD(...`) (because macros cannot contain dots), **(b)** you'd need to build this into the build process. You could then potentially do `gcc -E -P -D'LOGD(x)=' file.java` or `gcc -E -P -D'LOGD(x)=Log.d(x)' file.java`.

Comment: There are a few java "custom" preprocessors, but I doubt any of this is going to be "magic/plug and play". I'd try if the resources lookup is a problem first before diving into complicating your build/release process.